# Are there a definition of metric on continuous, non-differentiable manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

The definition of riemannian metric $g$ requires that the path $\gamma$ is differentiable, and thus the manifold is differentiable. To my understanding it is because that, to find the length of a curve $\gamma$, it needs to be differentiable. So this definition could be generalized to a Lipschitz manifold where the paths have weak derivatives?

What about a metric for a continuous manifold, in general?

---

This is a conceptual question not homework..

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530035/is-every-manifold-a-metric-space

Comment: Sullivan proved that every topological manifold of dimension $\ne 4$ admits a Lipschitz structure and that such a structure is unique up to a Lipshitz homeomorphism. Both fail in dimension 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that the [length of a continuous path](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~lang/LengthSpaces.pdf) $c: [0,1]\to X$ is defined in any metric space $(X,d)$, although some paths will have infinite length: 
$$
L(c)= \sup \sum_{i=1}^n d(c(t_{i-1}), c(t_i)),
$$
where the supremum is taken over all finite increasing sequences 
$$
0=t_0< t_1< ...< t_n=1.
$$

There are several ways to understand your question. Here is one:

Is it true that every connected topological manifold is "path-metrizable", i.e. admits a compatible metric $d$ such that the distance between any two points is the infimum of length of paths connecting these points?

This question has positive answer. Moreover:

**Theorem.** Let $X$ be a separable metrizable connected locally connected locally compact topological space. Then $X$ admits a complete *geodesic metric*, i.e. a metric such that every two points $p, q\in X$ are connected by a geodesic, i.e. a path whose length equals the distance between $p$ and $q$.

See

A. Tominaga and T. Tanaka, Convexification of locally connected generalized
continua, J. Sci. Hiroshima Univ. Ser A 19 (1955), 301-306.

Their proof builds upon the earlier work by Moise and Bing.

Connected topological manifolds satisfy the assumptions of this theorem, hence, they admit  complete geodesic metrics.