# Can speed be defined for a parametrized but irregular curve in a Riemannian manifold?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

My book is Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes by Loring W. Tu (I'll call this Volume 3), a sequel to both Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott (Volume 2) and An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu (Volume 1).

I refer to [Section 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ24U.png), [Section 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrukX.png), [Volume 1 Section 8.6 (Part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymqu2.png) and [Volume 1 Section 8.6 (Part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh4FW.png).

---

Use $t$ to denote the [standard coordinate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymqu2.png) on $[a,b]$, and use $t_0$ to denote a point in $[a,b]$. Let $x$ be the standard coordinate on $[0,l]$. **The speed** of a curve $c: [a,b] \to M$ into a Riemannian manifold $M$ **at a point** $t_0 \in [a,b]$ is defined $\|c'(t_0)\| := \sqrt{\langle c'(t_0), c'(t_0) \rangle_{t_0}}$. Then we can **define speed as a map** by $\|c'\|: [a,b] \to [0, \infty), (\|c'\|)(t_0) := \|c'(t_0)\|$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305415/does-st-0-ct-0-actually-mean-st-0-cong-ct-0-or), it seems to be claimed that this map $\|c'\|$ is the derivative of arc length function $s$ of $c$.

**Question**: In the first place, is $c$ supposed to be **assumed regular/an immersion** for the definition of speed $\|c'\|$, arc length $l$ or arc length function $s$, and why/why not?

My thoughts:

1. If $c$ is regular/an immersion, then $\|c'\|$ is smooth by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304443/can-a-riemannian-metric-always-be-induced-by-an-immersion-f-i-use-f-as-a-l), but I think it's possible to define $\|c'\|$, $l$ and $s$ for continuous $\|c'\|$. I can't think of a condition on $c$ to make $\|c'\|$ continuous but not necessarily smooth (see thought (2) below).

   - 1.1. **Edit: I actually didn't mention earlier**: Observe that in the paragraph before [Proposition 2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrukX.png), Tu uses the fundamental theorem of calculus. Based on [the version of FTC on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part), I think the rule behind FTC is something like

   > - "continuous $\mathbb R$-valued functions defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$ of $\mathbb R$ are Riemann integrable on $[a,t]$ for any $a<t\le b$"

   - Without such rule, I don't think we can define the "$F$" in [the version of FTC on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part). With such rule, if $\|c'\|$ (the "f") were continuous, then we could define $s$ (the "F") and thus define $l$. If $c$ is regular/an immersion, then $\|c'\|$ is smooth and thus continuous. If $c$ were irregular/not an immersion, then $\|c'\|$ is not necessarily smooth, I think (see thought (2) below). But we can still define $s$ (and thus define $l$) by the rule if $\|c'\|$ is somehow at least continuous.
2. It could be possible $\|c'\|$ is actually continuous or even smooth for an irregular/a non-immersion, but still smooth, $c$ because [in this question, Paulo Mourão can prove the smoothness part without immersion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268535/does-the-riemannian-metric-induced-by-a-diffeomorphism-f-exist-for-a-reason-ot).
3. **Update**: I think we can still define $\|c'\|$, $l$ and $s$ for an irregular/a non-immersion $c$ because there's this exercise: [Exercise 2.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/075XT.png), which asks for the arc length of a parametrized curve that was shown in [Example 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqugK.png) (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304560/are-cuspidal-cubics-topological-manifolds-smooth-submanifolds)) to be irregular/not an immersion. At the very least $l$ and $\|c'\|$ are defined. Not sure if $s$ is.

---

Context:

- [Does a curve parametrized by arc length have unit speed and its parameter starting at 0 even if not regular/not an immersion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312080/does-a-curve-parametrized-by-arc-length-have-unit-speed-and-its-parameter-starti)
- [If a curve $c$ can be reparametrized by arc length, then is $c$ regular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308263/if-a-curve-c-can-be-reparametrized-by-arc-length-then-is-c-regular)

Comment: One generalization you might find interesting is for absolutely continuous curves. I believe you should be able to define $c^\prime$ in the sense of the metric derivative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_derivative) using local coordinates, and then you can use the Riemannian inner product to compute $\Vert c^\prime (t) \Vert$.

Comment: @pseudocydonia Thanks. I assume you mean define $\|c'\|$ (with manifold implies [Riemannian manifold implies metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530035/is-every-manifold-a-metric-space)) and not $c'$ (asked about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3309064/636532)). Anyway, so indeed, $\|c'\|$, arc length $l$ or arc length function $s$ can be defined for irregular/non-immersion $c$?

Comment: Yes you're right, I was mistaken, the metric derivative should be able to give you the speed directly - it does not of course actually give you a vector $c^\prime$ in the tangent space.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good reference that goes into some detail, of how to work with absolutely continuous curves on Riemannian manifolds: http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2015/21-12v.pdf In other words, there is a reasonable extension of notions like the speed of a curve on a Riemannian manifold so that the answer to your question is negative.

Notably, a similar strategy sometimes allows you to work even with curves which are defined in an abstract metric space, with no manifold structure at all. For this, a good reference is the first half of the book by Ambrosio, Gigli, and Savaré.

Comment: Thanks. Wait, the issue I had in mind is using the assumption behind the fundamental theorem of calculus. I've forgotten the exact rule, but I think it's like "a continuous $\mathbb R$-valued function on a closed interval is Riemann integrable".  If $\|c'\|$ is continuous, then we can define $s$ (and thus $l$). If $c$ is regular, then $\|c'\|$ is smooth and thus continuous. 1. Now you're saying that if $c$ is still smooth but now also absolutely continuous (TIL smooth does not imply absolutely continuous), then $\|c'\|$ is at least continuous? 2. 2. If not...

Comment: 2. If not, then what do you mean? If so, then to strengthen as much as possible, what is the highest $k$ for $\|c'\| \in C^k[a,b]$ (just $k=0$, actually $k=\infty$, etc)?

Comment: You mean $c$ non-regular and $c$ smooth and absolutely continuous implies $\|c'\|$ is absolutely continuous? (Edit: pseudocydonia seems to have deleted the previous comment)

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke again. Absolute continuity should be sufficient to define arc length and the arc length function - no smoothness is required.

Comment: This is because the definition of absolute continuity *directly* gives you an arc length function if you look carefully.

Comment: Thanks. You don't have to be sorry. You mean 3. $c$ non-regular and $c$ absolutely continuous and smooth implies $\|c′\|$ is absolutely continuous? 4. And $c$ non-regular and $c$ absolutely continuous and smooth implies $\|c′\|$ is absolutely continuous, even if $c$ is not smooth, but with a different definition of $\|c′\|$ or $c'$? (I think I might think about (4) another day. For today, please just stick to (3).)

Comment: I don't know about that. I just meant that $c$ non-regular, absolutely continuous is enough for every section of the curve to have a well-defined arc length.

Comment: Oh wait I think I get you. Arc length here is defined as Riemann integral over domain of $||c'||$ (which is $[a,b]$) assuming we can Riemann integrate $||c'||$ over $[a,b]$. Now you're defining arc length in a way that doesn't involve $||c'||$, where your way doesn't even involve smoothness of $c$, so long as $c$ is absolutely continuous?

Comment: "In other words, there is a reasonable extension of notions like the speed of a curve on a Riemannian manifold so that the answer to your question is negative." 5. Why negative and not affirmative? (My question is defining speed for irregular/not an immersion) I suspect negative and not affirmative because of not assuming "absolutely continuous" 6. For **this particular notion of speed**:  can it be done without assuming $c$ regular/an immersion and without additional assumptions (e.g. absolute continuity)?

Comment: Yes and no - if you look at Section 3 of the paper I linked, it shows that *your particular notion of speed* is actually the same as the way one usually defines length for AC curves.

Comment: And another point is that $\Vert c^\prime \Vert$ need not be continuous, just Riemann/Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: 7. Are all of these correct please? 7.1 This notion of speed works for $c$ regular/an immersion. 7.2 This notion of speed works for $c$ not an immersion/irregular if $c$ is absolutely continuous. 7.3. This notion of speed does not work for $c$ not an immersion/irregular and $c$ not absolutely continuous.

Comment: 7.1 correct, 7.2 see comment below, 7.3 probably not correct. One issue, which I'm sure you've seen, is that non-immersive curves can cross themselves. At these points, the derivative is no longer well-defined. Therefore the notion of speed no longer makes any sense.

Comment: 8. Re "∥c′∥  need not be continuous, just Riemann/Lebesgue integrable": Maybe for your definition this is true, but for this definition, Tu explicitly uses fundamental theorem of calculus. Is there a version of FTC where instead of assuming $f$ continuous we assume $f$ Riemann integrable (the conclusions maybe different then, so we need not have $F$ uniformly continuous, but as long as $F$ is differentiable, then that's ok I guess; my version is based on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part))?

Comment: Thanks! Re (7.3), I said "does not work" not "works". Does your comment "probably not correct" indeed refer to "does not work", so it probably works for a way we haven't thought of?

Comment: Sorry, for 7.2: the point is that one can give various, *more general* definitons of length/speed which do *not* require the curve to be an immersion, but which nonetheless *coincide* with the definition you have given, for every curve which actually is an immersion.

Comment: And I misread, you are right for (7.3). It does not work for non-immersive curves, simply because the derivative tangent vector does not generally exist at every point.

Comment: How does Tu explicitly use the FTOC? I don't understand.

Comment: Thanks pseudocydonia! Tu uses (the) FTOC/FToC/FTC (part 1) in paragraph before [Proposition 2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrukX.png). I edited the question to hopefully be more explicit.

Comment: Do you agree with Max here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308263/if-a-curve-c-can-be-reparametrized-by-arc-length-then-is-c-regular

Comment: pseudocydonia, do we need or not need to assume $\|c'\|$ is continuous, if we can't deduce $\|c'\|$ is continuous? Is $\|c'\|$ is continuous for smooth but irregular $c$?