# Are arc length functions of regular curves immersions/submersions/local diffeomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

My book is Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes by Loring W. Tu (I'll call this Volume 3), a sequel to both Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott (Volume 2) and An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu (Volume 1).

Here are [Section 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ24U.png) and [Section 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrukX.png).

About [Proposition 2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrukX.png), I believe what happens is that we show $s$ is an immersion (or equivalently a submersion or a local diffeomorphism, by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298447/for-manifolds-of-the-same-dimension-are-submersions-equivalent-to-immersions) and by "Most of the concepts introduced for a manifold extend word for word to a manifold with boundary...", from [Volume 1 Section 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmETl.png)) and conclude that its inverse is smooth. I believe we can show $s$ is an immersion without deducing $s$ is bijective.

**Question 1: Is this right? Please verify.**

1. $||c'||: [a,b] \to (0,\infty)$ is a smooth map (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305412/for-a-parametrised-curve-probably-regular-ca-b-to-m-do-we-have-a-map)) because $c$ is regular/an immersion.
2. $||c'||$ is continuous by (1).
3. $\dot s = ||c'||$ by fundamental theorem of calculus and (2) (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305415/does-st-0-ct-0-actually-mean-st-0-cong-ct-0-or) for $\dot s$ vs $s'$).
4. Use $t$ denote the [standard coordinate (Volume 1 Section 8.6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymqu2.png) on $[a,b]$ but $t_0$ to denote a point in $[a,b]$. Then $\dot s(t_0) = ||c'(t_0)||$, for each $t_0 \in [a,b]$.
5. $s'(t_0)=\dot s(t_0) \frac{d}{dx}|_{s(t_0)}$, where $x$ is the [standard coordinate (Volume 1 Section 8.6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymqu2.png) on $[0,l]$, by [Volume 1 Exercise 8.14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymqu2.png), where $s'(t_0) := s_{*,t_0}[\frac{d}{dx}|_{s(t_0)}] \in T_{s(t_0)}[0,l]$ and where $s_{*,t_0}$ is $s_{*,t_0}: T_{t_0}[a,b] \to T_{s(t_0)}[0,l]$.
6. $s'(t_0)=||c'(t_0)|| \frac{d}{dx}|_{s(t_0)}$, by (4) and (5).
7. $s$ is an immersion if and only if $s_{*,t_0}$ is injective if and only if the kernel of $s_{*,t_0}$ consists only of $0_{t_0}$, the zero tangent vector of $T_{t_0}[a,b]$.
8. The kernel of $s_{*,t_0}$ consists only of $0_{t_0}$, the zero tangent vector of $T_{t_0}[a,b]$, as shown below.
9. Therefore, $s$ is an immersion by (7) and (8).

Proof of (8):

- 8.1. Suppose there exists $X_{t_0} \in T_{t_0}[a,b]$ such that $s_{*,t_0}[X_{t_0}] = 0_{s(t_0)}$, the zero tangent vector of $T_{s(t_0)}[0,l]$.
- 8.2. Such $X_{t_0}$ in (8.1) is $X_{t_0)} = a(t_0) \frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0}$ for some real number $a(t_0)$.
- 8.3. $0_{s(t_0)} = s_{*,t_0}[X_{t_0}] = s_{*,t_0}[a(t_0) \frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0}] = a(t_0) s_{*,t_0}[\frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0}] = a(t_0)s'(t_0) = a(t_0)||c'(t_0)|| \frac{d}{dx}|_{s(t_0)}$, by (6), (8.1) and (8.2).
- 8.4 $||c'(t_0)|| = 0$ if and only if $c'(t_0) = 0_{c(t_0)}$, the zero tangent vector in $T_{c(t_0)}M$.
- 8.5. $c'(u_0)$ is not $0_{c(u_0)}$ for all $u_0 \in [a,b]$, which is the - definition of $c$ regular/an immersion.
- 8.6. $||c'(u_0)|| \ne 0$ for all $u_0 \in [a,b]$ by (8.4) and (8.5).
- 8.7. $0_{s(t_0)} = a(t_0) \frac{d}{dx}|_{s(t_0)}$ by (8.3) and (8.6).
- 8.8. $a(t_0) = 0$ by (8.7) and by definition of $0_{s(t_0)} := 0 \frac{d}{dx}|_{s(t_0)}$
- 8.9. $X_{t_0} = 0 \frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0} = 0_{t_0}$ by (8.1), (8.8) and by definition of $0_{t_0} := 0 \frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0}$.

**Question 2: Do I use bijectiveness of s anywhere above?**

Comment: What is even the point of this? You've turned something really simple into something really obtuse, and for what? You need that $s$ is a bijection because it is the inverse function to $s$ that is needed to reparametrize $c$ to obtain the arclength parametrization.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Just wanted to clarify if bijectiveness is needed to prove immersiveness of $s$...

Comment: "Immersiveness" is not a particular useful notion for $s$. There is no reason to think of $s$ as a map between manifolds here. Instead, just consider it a function on an interval into the real line. It is true that $s$ can be considered to be an immersion into $\Bbb R$, or a diffeomorphism with its image, but that is because any two open intervals in $\Bbb R$ are diffeomorphic. The only thing required of a surjective smooth function between two open intervals to be a diffeomorphism is that the derivative is never $0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks. Re first comment: Good insight and intuition.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Re second comment: I know immersions are equivalent to local embeddings, and I guess local embeddings are "locally injective" (I never bothered to look up the precise definition for "locally injective"), but how are immersions injective? I think you meant to say $F_{*,p}$ is injective if and only if $F$ is an immersion at p if and only if $\ker F_{*,p} = 0_p$, but it sounds like you're saying "$F$ immersion implies $F$ injective". Please clarify

Comment: I apologize for that. I was thinking of an embedding. I deleted the comment because it was just plain wrong.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You don't have to apologize. Thanks. You can answer if you want.