# If a curve $c$ can be reparametrized by arc length, then is $c$ regular?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

My book is Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes by Loring W. Tu (I'll call this Volume 3), a sequel to both Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott (Volume 2) and An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu (Volume 1).

I refer to [Section 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ24U.png), [Section 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrukX.png), [Volume 1 Section 8.6 (Part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymqu2.png), [Volume 1 Section 8.6 (Part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh4FW.png) and this question: [Does "$s'(t_0) = ||c'(t_0)||$" actually mean "$s'(t_0) \cong ||c'(t_0)||$" or "$\dot s(t_0) = ||c'(t_0)||$"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305415/does-st-0-ct-0-actually-mean-st-0-cong-ct-0-or)

---

**Question**: [Proposition 2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrukX.png) says if $c$ is regular, then $s$ is a diffeomorphism. Conversely, If $s$ somehow is a diffeomorphism, then is $c$ regular?

- **Context**: I'm wondering if [Proposition 2.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrukX.png) should instead start "A *regular* curve is parametrized..." To be clear, I think [Proposition 2.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrukX.png) says:

  - > Let $c$ be a (not sure if regular or not) parametrized curve. If $c:[a,b] \to M$, for real numbers $a$ and $b$, can be reparametrized by arc length, i.e. we can define a (regular I guess) curve $\gamma := c \circ t: [\alpha,  \beta] \to [a,b] \to M$ for some diffeomorphism $t$ and for some real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then $\gamma$, the reparametrized $c$, is also regular and has unit speed and $\alpha = 0.$ (Of course, we later show $\beta = l$.) Conversely, if $c:[a,b] \to M$, for real numbers $a$ and $b$ is such that $c$ has unit speed and $a=0$, ($b=l$ is not used here, but I have a feeling $b=l$ can substitute for $a=0$. Not sure.) then the parameter $t$ of $c=c(t)$, is actually arc length.

    - I also assume the condition, in [Proposition 2.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrukX.png), "is parametrized by arc length" (or "can be reparametrized by arc length", depending on your version) is equivalent to the conclusion of [Proposition 2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrukX.png), which is the existence of (**Note**: Edited to add the word smooth) *smooth* $s^{-1}$. If this assumption is wrong, then the question in the title is different from the one in the body.
  - **Updates**:

    - A. I forgot to mention in the previous paragraph that I think the the conclusion of [Proposition 2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrukX.png) is that $s^{-1}$ exists *and is smooth*.
    - B. I'm actually not sure $t$ is a diffeomorphism for the "is parametrized by arc length". It could be that $t$ is just smooth. But maybe $t$ is a diffeomorphism based on [Section 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ24U.png).
    - C. I'm actually not sure $s^{-1}$ exists *and is smooth* is equivalent to "$s$ is a diffeomorphism". Actually, if $c$ is regular, then $s$ is smooth and has a smooth inverse too. If $s$ has an inverse that is smooth (or even just differentiable) *and $s$ is smooth*, then $c$ I guess is regular, as pointed out in answer below. However, If $s$ has an inverse that is smooth (or even just differentiable) *but $s$ is not necessarily smooth*, then I'm not sure $c$ is regular. Waiting for response in comments in answer below. I think we need $s$ at least differentiable, which I think follows from FTC, assuming the hypotheses of FTC are satisfied. (I actually ask about the use of [FTC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305412/can-speed-be-defined-for-a-parametrized-curve-that-is-not-regular-not-an-immersi) here.)
- **More context**:

  - [Can speed be defined for a parametrized curve that is not regular/not an immersion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305412/for-a-parametrised-curve-probably-regular-an-immersion-ca-b-to-m-do-we)
  - [Does a curve parametrized by arc length have unit speed and its parameter starting at 0 even if not regular/not an immersion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312080/a-curve-is-parametrized-by-arc-length-if-and-only-if-it-has-unit-speed-and-its-p)

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the issues is that there is no explicit definition of what it means for a curve to be "parametrized by arc length".  The implicit definition use in the proof of 2.4 is that a curve is parametrized by arclength if it is given as   $\gamma(s)=c(t(s))$  for some regular curve $c$, with $t(s)$ the inverse of the arclength function $s(t)$ of $c$. Since Prop 2.3 guaratees that $t(s)$ exists only when $c$ is regular, this definition a priori only makes sense under the assumption that  $c$ is  regular (and of course then $\gamma$ can be proved to is regular as in the second part of Prop 2.4 (in fact $|\gamma'(s)|=1$ so $\gamma'(s)\neq 0$)).

Now your question can be interpreted as "can $t(s)$ exist for non-regular $c$"?

The answer is that if you require $t$ to be differentiable (which is part of saying that $s$ is a diffeomorphism), then it follows that $c$ is regular, since $s(t(s))=s$ and differentiating $s'(t)t'(s)=1$, and by main thm of calculus $s'(t)=|c'(t)|$, so $|c'(t)||t'(s)|=1|$, so $c'(t)\neq 0$ (on the other hand, if you only require $t$ to be a continuous inverse for $s$ then you can find plenty of examples where $c$ is non-regular, and they can then be "reparametrized by a continuous change of parameter"; however the resulting $\gamma(s)$ has no reason to be continuous, much less smooth (but can be arranged to be smooth in some cases)). In summary, if $c$ is regular all the definitions make sense and and resulting $\gamma$ is smooth. If $c$ is not regular, $t(s)$ can not be smooth, but sometimes can still exists, however other things will usually break.

Comment: THANKS SO SO MUCH. I was really afraid that I should somehow know the definition of "parametrized by arc length".

Comment: 1. Actually, may you please clarify your assumptions on $s$? If $c$ is regular then, $s$ and $\|c'\|$ are smooth. If $c$ is not regular, then I think "$s^{-1}$ is smooth" and "$s$ diffeomorphism" are not equivalent. (I ask about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3305412/636532))

Comment: 2. Is this correct? 2.1. $c$ regular implies $s$ diffeo. 2.2. $s$ smooth bijective with differentiable inverse (as in between $C^0$ and $C^1$) implies $c$ regular.  2.3. $s$ smooth bijective with differentiable inverse implies $t$ smooth (i.e. $s$ and $t$ diffeo) by (2.1) and (2.2).

Comment: 3. To clarify, the problem with the lack of a definition for "parametrized by arc length" is that it doesn't say what $C^k$ $t$ is, but indeed for $k=\infty$, the converse of Proposition 2.3 is true (and still true for $t$ differentiable instead of $t$ smooth)?

Comment: 2 is correct. I don't understand your comment about t being $C^k$. If $c$ is smooth, then as soon as $t(s)$ is differentiable, we get that $s$ has non-zero derivative and $c$ is regular, so both $s$ and $t$ are smooth. So, if by "converse" you mean that "s has differentiable inverse implies c is regular" then this is true.

Comment: Thanks Max. For 1: Any comment please? For 2: Done here.

Comment: For 3: You said "The answer is that if you require t to be differentiable". This led me to the idea that part of the missing definition of "parametrized by arc length" is how $C^k$ that $t$ is. It doesn't really say if $t$ is smooth, $t$ is differentiable, $t$ is $C^1$, $t$ is continuous or anything. So if $t$ is anything less than differentiable (I guess this is $C^{0.5}$, right in between continuous and $C^1$), then "t exists implies c is regular" may or may not be true? (Probably absolutely continuous somehow works)

Comment: Do you agree with pseudocydonia here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305412/can-speed-be-defined-for-a-parametrized-curve-that-is-not-regular-not-an-immersi